# Start wine graphical application from .desktop file

Tags: gnome, wine, .desktop, desktop-icons

#### Context

I'm trying to start Ableton Live which I installed through wine (and is working perfectly might I add!) by simply clicking on an icon in the taskbar.

#### Normal behavior

If I run the command from a terminal, which looks like `wine /path/to/program.exe` everything works perfectly: I get a bunch of information messages in the terminal, and a window pops up with Ableton inside it.

#### Problematic behavior

The problem is that as soon as I run it from a `.desktop` file nothing happens. I tried setting the `Terminal=true`flag, and then it pops a terminal with the messages that I normally see on my terminal: so I know the program is launching... There is just no display.

#### My guess

I'm not an expert so forgive me if I use the wrong terms, but my guess is that it has something to do with the window server. Since when I start it from my session it's fine, but somehow when started from the `.desktop` it can't display, it seems the obvious culprit. I suppose it's started from another session that can't display windows. The only problem with that guess is I read everywhere that `.desktop` files are running commands as the user, I even ran `whoami` in a `.desktop` to confirm it... So I'm at a loss to what the next step is.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after playing around with it I came to the conclusion my initial hypothesis was wrong, the problem is not on the Linux side of things.

When you start `wine`, linux is mounted on drive `Z:` to the path of your terminal, for instance:

```
/some/path$ wine cmd.exe
Z:\some\path>
```

I guess wine needs that path to be coherent somehow, because I realized that when you start it from the `.desktop` the path doesn't match and all the issues I had stem from this. I fixed it by replacing the command:

```
wine "C:\path\to\program"
```

with

```
wine cmd.exe /c "C:" "&" "C:\path\to\program"
```

This way I completely remove the need to track where I am in `Z:`, and what do you know: now the UI shows up!

I'm not entirely sure why it works, but it does so... eh! I hope this can help someone else!